# Dropdown Menu Items not showing up in dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The items in my dropdown menu will not appear, the menu itself does but not the items.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.html">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

I grabbed it from bootstrap and checked all my CSS but nothing seems to work

Tried changing all the css that would affect it, and nothing changed.

Comment: Add bootstrap js `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add Bootstrap Popper and Bootstrap JS separately or add Bootstrap Bundle JS.
- If you want to use dropdowns, popovers, or tooltips then you need to add Popper JS CDN otherwise they are not working.